# Multiline Regex - Find specific string within special bounds

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have been teaching myself RegEx and have run into a roadblock. This is an example of what I am searching through.

```
  Object : DmpFbkPrg
Type : InfinityProgram
LastChange : 8/14/2009 2:34:35 PM
   DeviceId : ISD535Main\GibbsCX\RmB131Vav
   Alias : DmpFbkPrg
   CreateTime : 8/14/2009 2:21:01 PM
   CreatedBy : Root\ISD535_Admin\Users\jocoffman
   ByteCode : 
Init:

  DmpReset State = Enabled

   EndByteCode
  EndObject

  Object : DmpPrg
   Type : InfinityProgram
   LastChange : 8/31/2009 8:22:19 PM
   DeviceId : ISD535Main\GibbsCX\RmB131Vav
   Alias : DmpPrg
   CreateTime : 8/14/2009 2:21:01 PM
   CreatedBy : Root\ISD535_Admin\Users\jocoffman
   ByteCode :
x
x
x z = xx
x
x
   EndByteCode
   Status : Active
  EndObject
```

My goal is to select from `Object` to `EndObject` as long as it contains the string `z =`.

I have tried Negative lookbehind and lookahead but what happens is it will match from the Fbk Object to the last EndObject rather than the DmpPrg to EndObject.

This is a basis of what I have tried with many alterations. I have placed the negative lookahead/lookbehind before the (?:z =) and a few other spots with no luck.

```
(Object : ((?:.*?)(?<!Reset)(?:Vlv|Pos|Dmp|MAD|Fan|Wheel|Spd|Valve)(?!(?:Fbk|Reset|RadVlv))(?:.*?))\r\n(.*)(?:Type : InfinityProgram)[\s\S]*?(?:Alias : \2)[\s\S]*?(?:Code :))[\s\S]*?(?:z =)[\s\S]*?EndObject
```

Comment: Use `Object(?s:(?!Object).)*?z =(?s:.*?)EndObject`. Do not use `[\s\S]`, use `.` with the `(?s)` inline modifier. or `(?s:...)` modifier group.

Comment: Is there a way to add in the ByteCode : line. I need these as part of my replace function. And thank you so much, I have been going crazy with this.

Comment: Do you mean you need to capture the part between `ByteCode :` until (and excluding) `EndByteCode`?

Comment: I would need to capture from Object to Byte Code: then from after ByteCode : to EndObject. I would then replace with \1\nNumeric Testz, Test2z, etc\2.

Comment: Not sure, but the main idea is still to use a tempered greedy token, see an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/jwiUQc/1).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. This is a huge help. I had not seen anything about ?s until now.

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html